# Multiple passes per yield with fit_generator()?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have an application where gathering data from file is expensive so I want to grab a batch of training data and train on it for multiple iterations before grabbing more.  If I make a generator to grab data from file, it appears that `fit_generator()` will only use that data once and then call the generator again.  Is there a way to make `fit_generator()` use the same data for multiple passes of training?  Or is the correct solution to embed this feature into my generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build a new generator that wraps another generator.

```
def repeater_generator(generator, reps=10):
    while True:
        batch = next(generator)
        for i in range(reps):
            yield batch
```

Should be something like that.